# Erro de conversao de int para String

Tags: c

Esse meu codigo que estou usando pra estudar C, nao esta convertendo (pelo menos eh o que eu acho)  a INT temp10 para CHAR...  aparecendo um erro:

**linha 5:  5182 Falha de segmentação  (imagem do núcleo gravada)**

O que pode ser?

```
int main() {
    // aqui esta tudo OK!
    char tempA[100] = "11";
    printf("COUVE = %s\n", tempA);

    strcpy(tempA, "22");
    printf("CEREJA = %s\n", tempA);

    strcpy(tempA, "kk");
    outraFuncao(tempA);

    //  mas se transformo um int em string:
    temp6 = 1000;
    temp7 =  100;
    temp8 =   10;
    temp9 =    1;
    temp10= temp6+temp7+temp8+temp9;
    char temp10=temp10+'0';

    printf("\n\n\n");
    //  da falha de segmentacao na hora do print
    printf("CEREJA2 = %s\n", temp10);

    //  aqui vai ser importante para meu programa... chamar um funcao com esse valor convertido de int para char
    //  mas o mesmo erro defalha desegmentacao acontece..
    outraFuncao(temp10);
} 


void outraFuncao(char *temp) {
    //  strcpy(temp, "33");
    printf("AMORA = %s\n", temp);
}
```

Comment: Esse código não faz o menor sentido, então é difícil até começar ajudar. Não tem nada convertendo alguma coisa. Nem sei se precisa. Tem muita coisa que não precisa estar aí. Na verdade o código todo não faz nada muito útil. Não serve nem como exercício. Além disso você parece ignorar o que é dito, então fica complicado.

Comment: A questão é: pra que converter alguma coisa se você já pode usar o que deseja diretamente? Eu nem tentei responder porque só vai resolver o seu problema, sem te ensinar nada útil. De que adianta eu te dar a solução para isso, se isso que está fazendo está todo errado? Eu não sei qual é o objetivo, mas esse código não ajuda aprender nada. Não sei se pegou para fazer isso em algum lugar. Eu sei que precisa fazer de outra forma ou perguntar coisas que vão te ajudar de verdade.

Comment: Eu sugiro fazer como o José X falou, pegue um livro e comece aprender estruturadamente. Talvez até começar por um linguagem mais fácil. Normalmente eu costumo indicar começar por C mesmo, ainda que quase todo mundo seja contra. Mas há casos e casos. C é uma linguagem muito cheia de detalhe. Com "exercícios" sem sentido não vai aprender. Precisa de algo que te guie, que vá apresentando cada conceito, um por vez, na ordem certa,coisas que tenham relevância.Aí fazendo os exercícios sugeridos no livro terá dúvidas e será + fácil perguntar aqui.Temo q esse código está + prejudicando o aprendizado

Comment: Outra possibilidade é procurar um bom curso, não sei se tem na sua cidade. Quando se está perdido, uma ajuda individualizada e guiada é importante.Estou tentando te mostrar que esse caminho adotado não vai te ajudar, precisa optar por outra forma de aprendizado. Tome cuidado com opções fáceis e baratas (tipo tutorais e vídeos na internet), elas prejudicam mais que ajudam.

Comment: obrigado pela atencao,  mas nao desejo lhe pertubar mais, ja aprovei uma resposta.  vamos deixar isso pra la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

isso aqui **NÃO** está transformado uma `int` numa string, está convertendo um `int` em **UM** caracter... simplesmente não faz sentido

```
 temp10= temp6+temp7+temp8+temp9;
 char temp10=temp10+'0';
```

---

aqui dá falha de segmentação porque `temp10` **NÃO** é uma string, então você não pode usar o formato "%s", tem que ser o formato "%d"

```
 printf("\n\n\n");
 //  da falha de segmentacao na hora do print
 printf("CEREJA2 = %s\n", temp10);
```

---

uma maneira de transformar um int numa `string` é com a função `snprintf`

```
char buf[20];
snprintf(buf, 20, "CEREJA=%d\n", temp10);
```

---

mas em seu exemplo nem precisa disso, pode simplesmente fazer assim

```
printf("CEREJA=%d\n", temp10);
```

---

Comment: sugiro você estudar seguindo algum livro para iniciantes...me parece que esse aqui "C para Iniciantes" do Deitel é bem conceituado
http://www.livrariacultura.com.br/p/c-como-programar-22679852
ps. se for comprar o livro, prepare-se para morrer com uma grana preta :)

outra opção seria fazer algum curso presencial, mas não sei onde indicar